# Why doesn't Russia assassinate Zelenskyy with a rocket?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, rules-of-war, assassinations

Remember Dzhokhar Dudaev? He led the Chechens during their first uprising against Russia in die 90s and was assassinated by Russia in 1996 who used a rocket to kill him in the streets of Grozny.

Currently, Russia is fighting its democratic neighbor Ukraine in a bloody and expensive war it seems incapable to win. One of the strengths of Ukraine is undoubtedly their charismatic leader Volodymyr Zelenskyy who succeeded in uniting not only the Ukrainians against the aggressor, but also almost all of the decision makers of the Western World.

My question is - Why did Russia not assassinate Zelenskyy using a rocket? They don't even have to establish a no fly zone, Russia is demonstrating each and every day of the war that they are able to use long range rockets to hit targets all over Ukraine, sometimes very precisely even. Even more interestingly - Zelenskyy himself has been using social media and TV to show each and every day that he is alive and working actively, often doing that outside in the streets of Ukraines capital Kyiv. In many cases it is quite easy to find out to which places he goes often just by looking at his self-published footage.

To be clear - I do not hope that this happens, quite the opposite, I fear that this might happen and thus wonder why Russia has not done that yet and why Zelenskyy is giving away his positions so often and openly.

Comment: One can assume that the option has been discussed, but no one outside Putin's circle is going to know the real reasons.  Besides, assassinating political leaders tends to turn them into heroes/martyrs for people to rally around.

Comment: This might be more a military question than a politics question. I'm sure Russia is trying to kill Zelenskyy but did not have the means yet. Maybe it's not that simple. But then I'm not an expert in military capabilities.

Comment: I know this is a military stack exchange question but there is no military stack exchange.

Comment: This would be off-topic in politics. The political aspect is answered in that Ukraine has claimed to have foiled over a dozen assassination attempts since the start of the war already. Further complicated by the fact that we cannot confirm if rockets shot down were aimed at him.

Comment: I don´t think this question can be answered with facts. So this is really a speculation then, Zelenski has worked in Russia some time, so he might still have some conections there and this conections helping him to survive.

Comment: They keep trying but this is another example of the Russian military not being up to spec.

Comment: From what Russia has said it sounds like they're holding back somewhat. E.g. in https://www.reuters.com/world/uk/russia-warns-britain-provoking-ukraine-2022-04-26/, Russia threatens a "proportional response" if Ukraine attacks targets in Russia. Something similar could explain why Russia isn't specifically targeting Zelenskyy - they are at the moment not waging total war.

Comment: If they do kill Zelenskyy they likely make a matyr out of him - he isn't a military commander.

Comment: Acording to Israely PM Putin promised him to not Kill Zelensky.

Answer (score 13):

Because they can't. Zelensky spends most of his time [in a bunker](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-61113079), presumably ex-Soviet, so proof against any missile attack short of a nuke (and possibly even that). He does venture above ground from time to time, but briefly and unpredictably, specifically so that he can't be targeted.

Comment: adding to this is that, well according to the information that has been doing the rounds (and keep in mind that Ukraine *will* manipulate info to its benefit even if they are the good guys), Zelensky has been targetted by [Wagner assassin squads](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/ukraines-zelensky-survives-three-assassination-attempts-this-week-report/).  The circumstances of that report are weird though.

Comment: There's no proof in your link for your assertion of where he spends most of his time. The word bunker isn't even in the article.

Answer (score 3):

No one knows for sure, but there are a few reasons that may be relevant:

- It does not solve any immediate military objectives for Russia. It would surely cause stakes to rise, but that's it. This is probably the same reason why there are no attempts to assassinate Putin, btw.
- Russia may eventually want to sign a peace treaty with Ukraine. After all, wars are fought to have a better peace. If Ukraine does not have any legal, alive leadership at this point this becomes complicated.
- At this point, Russia avoids targeting civilian objects - a president is a civilian target, too. There seems to be a change in this - the recent campaign of bombing fuel refineries and railway stations shows that dual-use objects are now targeted. So it is conceivable that this reason will become invalid in the future. Why Russia employs this strategy is another question.

But the real answer is, no one knows for sure.

Comment: "It does not solve any immediate military objectives for Russia." Zelenskyy may formally be the highest commander of the Ukrainian army. And his public transmissions to the whole world surely has not only increased the will to fight for Ukrainians but may also be responsible for many of the weaponry that is delivered to Ukraine. I could imagine that there would be strategic value in killing him and that he would also be a valid target. The same way that killing Putin would probably a worthwhile goal for Ukrainians.

Comment: Killing president of a country may also trigger a lot of weapon deliveries to it. It may also by itself increase the will of Ukrainian army to resist. Martyrs are a thing.

Comment: *At this point, Russia avoids targeting civilian objects*  That's... an odd statement to be making.  Not gonna downvote, each is entitled to their opinion, but, wow, Mariupol much?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I guess I should've made myself clearer - it *looks* like Russia is not going to deliberately *bomb* a purely civilian target unless it thinks it has Ukrainian army inside (hence, no longer civilian). Russia is still *absolutely* going to capture towns and cities, and that involves *a lot* of collateral damage.

Comment: It's definitely untrue that Russia is avoiding to bomb civilian targets.  Russia, without a doubt, targets civilians to deliberately cause civilian suffering as a matter of policy.

Comment: @wrod I don't think Russia is wasting ammunition in uncontested areas. The only places they are using bombs are areas where they don't have total control (Ukrainian army holds the city). So civilians are likely collateral damage. Even under the Geneva conventions, civilian casualties are allowed so long as the anticipated military gain is proportional.

Comment: @uberhaxed they are shooting at civilian convoys after agreeing to let them pass. they have killed entire towns of civilians under their control.  they have bombed civilian neighborhoods with no military targets. they have stated that their goal is to destroy Ukrainians as an ethnic group.

Comment: @wrod any independent entity to verify any of your claims? For obvious reasons, sources from parties of the war (either Russia or Ukraine) are not independent.

Comment: @uberhaxed i don't know what "claims" you are talking about.  Russia is not hiding this.  Putin has bestowed special honors on the the soldiers which conducted the ethnic cleansing in Butcha, after the world learned of the murders.  The genocide proclamation was made by Putin's propaganda machine.  These were not some behind-the-secret-door proclamations.  These were public proclamations.  The propagandists have tried to push "мне не стыдно" (eng.: "I am not ashamed") hashtag on Russia's national television.  They are not hiding this.  They take pride in it.

Comment: @wrod Sources from Russian media (your source) are not independent, I just told you this. Do you have a different source than Russian state media for any of the statements you just made? Obviously, media from Ukraine falls under the same category. I find it actually unbelievable that you are using statements from the Kremlin as fact...

Comment: @uberhaxed these are statements against self-interest.  when they say something that is self-damning, there is no reason to question it.  and the fact that Putin has bestowed honors on the killers of Butcha doesn't need confirmation.  It's self-confirming.  He did it on TV.  And no, there is nothing obvious about Ukrainian sources being in any way equivalent to Russian sources.  Russia has passed laws outlawing independent opinions.  Ukraine has only outlawed direct support of Russia, but it has not outlawed questioning government sources.  And it has independent journalists.

Comment: @wrod it doesn't matter what the content is, war  parties are not reliable sources of information. Wartime propaganda is not only common, but accepted everywhere in the world. Countries will, for example, give completely false casualty numbers to 1. Increase moral and 2. Not give their enemies accurate information to assess their strength. That's why you cannot trust anything from belligerents during wartime and need independent sources. They will say anything on tv just to rile up their population. During WWI the Spanish flu wasn't even mentioned except by Spain because they were independent.

Comment: @uberhaxed you can always trust self-certifying statements.  Someone making a public proclamation X creates evidence that they made a public proclamation X.  This is a self-certifying event.  It doesn't need independent verification.

Comment: @wrod Russia makes public proclamations that it won't target civilians specifically. I'm not talking whether Russia is successful with sticking to that strategy neither if it actually saves lives. I'm just saying that's how public discussion goes.