# Bombing Ukraine president location

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, assassinations

I have read multiple news stories that, at the beginning of the war, Russia knew of Volodymyr Zelenskyy's location. They tried to send assassination squads to kill him but failed. A few weeks back Zelenskyy himself told news media where he was and openly challenged Russia to come and get him.

My question is: If one of Russia's main goals is to decapitate the Ukrainian government by killing its president then why doesn't it concentrate all its bombings on that one location? Air power, artillery, cruise missiles, bunker buster bombs, etc. If he's somewhere underground then drop limited radius chemical weapons everyday on that location. Other heads of state from different countries and major news networks seem to be visiting him on a weekly basis so tracking them and thus Zelenskyy's location won't be a problem. Multiple drones or attack aircraft flying overhead 24/7 so that as soon as he steps out in public, send a missile.

Does Russia have no good satellite or surveillance programs to know where Zelenskyy is each and every moment or are they just inept. I don't get it.

Comment: Apart form Zelensky there are no independant sorces prooving his story. Aslo there is some kind of similar question here somewhere asking why Russia not killing Zelensky.

Comment: @convert - https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/72819/26455

Comment: @TimurShtatland sorry no not really. most voted answer was more of a speculation than a detailed answer or analysis.

Comment: @SamB, well, what more than speculation could there be on a 'why does *X* does *Y*' question if *X* has been willing to use deception?

Comment: Relevant? [What exactly are the stated (political and military) objectives of the 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72072/what-exactly-are-the-stated-political-and-military-objectives-of-the-2022-russ)

Answer (score 4):

Russia apparently did make [some attempt](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/world/europe/zelenskiy-says-russia-came-close-to-capturing-him-at-start-of-invasion-1.4865247) to capture/kill Zelenskyy at the start of the war, but since then they've held back; in fact they have avoided attacking Ukraine's decision-making centers [directly](https://globalnews.ca/news/8787436/russia-ukrain-kyiv-attack-western-presence/):

> The Russian military so far has avoided striking presidential, government and military headquarters in Kyiv during its campaign in Ukraine that has entered a third month.

They undoubtedly can launch these attacks, so they clearly lack the desire to do it. Why? Nobody except the Russian high command knows. I would guess that the assumption that one of Russia's goals is to "decapitate the Ukrainian government" is incorrect, but it's a guess - nobody except the Russian high command knows.

Comment: It's clear the original plan/ theory was that a blitz to Kyiv along with elimination of the Ukrainian leadership would lead to a collapse of any opposition to the invasion and the Ukrainian army would quickly surrender.  It's quite clear at this point that isn't going to work, thus killing Zelensky would serve no real purpose.  The realistic best case scenario for Russia at this point is some kind of settlement -- this requires opposition leaders to negotiate with.

Comment: You should probably add "allegedly" to the first sentence. Your source is a single person which benefits greatly from hearsay...

Comment: Capturing him is likely to have been a more probable goal, per the article you've linked. Or causing him to flee, which would have made a Russia-backed regime more easy to install. The Kremlin has been rather vague what they meant by "denazify". But events in cities like Kherson do shed some light what that means in practice.